# Error handling between multiple modules and subroutines

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I had a single module with a single working subroutine that was very long.

I decided to chop it up into smaller chunks.

I now have a half dozen modules and several of the modules contain multiple subroutines (like 6 or less). One module contains all my functions for example (like 10 functions). One subroutine (RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_MAIN) defines several variables and calls the other modules, like this:

```
Sub RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_MAIN()

    Public Path As String
    Public wkbTemp As Workbook
    Public StartTime As Double
    Public CurrentDateTime As Date
       'Etc....

       'Do some stuff....

    Call RT_SETUP_WKBTEMP
    Call RT_COMPILE_TABLE_HEADER
    Call RT_RUN_LOG
    Call RT_SAVE_WORKBOOKS

       'Do some stuff....

    Application.Quit

End Sub

Sub LogError(ErrorMsg As String)

    wkbErrorLog.Activate

    On Error Resume Next

    Range("A" & LRow).Value = CurrentData_FilePath
    Range("B" & LRow).Value = CurrentDateTime
    Range("C" & LRow).Value = ErrorMsg
        'Etc....

    wkbErrorLog.Save
    wkbErrorLog.Saved = True

    Application.Quit

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This has made working with the code easier with one exception. I am not sure how to handle the Error handling. For example, part of my code checks to see if a file is a txt or csv file. If it is neither, I want it to go to `Sub LogError(ErrorMsg As String)`. My intention is to make a single error handler that would be used by all the various modules and subroutines.

```
Sub RT_SETUP_WKBTEMP()

    If File_Extension = "txt" Then
        Call RT_FORMAT_TXT_FILE
    ElseIf File_Extension = "csv" Then
        Call RT_FORMAT_CSV_FILE
    Else
        Call LogError("Not a .csv or .txt file")
    End If

        'Do some more stuff.....

End Sub
```

However, I see that because `Sub RT_SETUP_WKBTEMP()` "Calls" the error handler subroutine, it comes back to `Sub RT_SETUP_WKBTEMP()` where it left off after running through the error handler subroutine. I don't want this. I want the program to end after running through the error handler subroutine.

Comment: Without getting into potentially refactoring your code, you can use the [`Exit Sub` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/exit-statement) or even the [`End` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement) to immediately terminate execution of the macro -- but you should note that this type of immediate shutdown is not necessarily a "clean" exit where you could save/erase/undo intermediate data or other things your program has half-completed.

Comment: Peter's suggestion should work, just to clarify on it, you should put the 'Exit Sub' statement after the call and before the 'End If'. You can put the 'End' statement inside the LogError() sub at the very end if you wish to always terminate execution when the sub is called. Keep in mind Peter's warnings though.

Comment: Thank you... I was hoping to receive a solution potentially this simple. Which would be better... Exit sub? or End? Or what are the pros/cons/differences between using each? Also, you said "Without getting into potentially refactoring your code." What did you mean by this? Is there a better / different way to go about organizing my code?

Comment: Ok... I figured it out... In the first module I put "on error goto error handler" and put an error handler in the first module. The error handler calls the "Sub LogError(ErrorMsg As String)" then after the sub run it returns to the error handler and the program ends... Lastly, I changed my if statement to (Err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 513, Description:="Not a .csv or .txt file"). Effectively, artificially creating an error which sends the program automatically from the child module to the error handler in the mother module.

Comment: You might want to check out Functions, they can return values. Global Variables are something you should avoid in most cases.

Comment: Or if you want to go OOPish, pack the values you need to pass around into a class and then pass an object of this class around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already indicated in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360151/trouble-with-error-handling-between-multiple-modules-and-subroutines/57384842#comment101213835_57360151), you can raise a custom error and handle it with an error handler. You can also use On Error... to log the entire call stack. Once an error occurred, the On Error... in the current procedure no longer applies, and error handling is passed to the calling procedure, from which you can write another error log entry:

```
Public Path As String
Public wkbTemp As Workbook
Public StartTime As Double
Public CurrentDateTime As Date
   Etc....

Sub RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_MAIN()
    Do some stuff....

    On Error GoTo ErrHandlerMain
    Call RT_SETUP_WKBTEMP
    Call RT_COMPILE_TABLE_HEADER
    Call RT_RUN_LOG
    Call RT_SAVE_WORKBOOKS

    Do some stuff....
ErrorExit:
    'Clean up and exit
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Quit

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

ErrHandlerMain:
    Call LogError("Error in Sub RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_MAIN")
    Resume ErrorExit 'Go to the clean-up code and Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub RT_SETUP_WKBTEMP()
    Const iCUSTOM_ERROR As Integer = 513 
    On Error GoTo ErrHandlerSetup
    If File_Extension = "txt" Then 
        Call RT_FORMAT_TXT_FILE 
    ElseIf File_Extension = "csv" Then 
        Call RT_FORMAT_CSV_FILE 
    Else
        'This error will be handled by ErrHandlerSetup
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + iCUSTOM_ERROR
    End If

    'Do some more stuff.....

    Exit Sub

ErrHandlerSetup:
    Call LogError("Error in Sub RT_SETUP_WKBTEMP: Not a .csv or .txt file")

    'Raise another error, which will be handled by ErrHandlerMain in Sub RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_MAIN
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + iCUSTOM_ERROR
End Sub

Sub LogError(ErrorMsg As String)
    'Modified to not include any clean-up code
    wkbErrorLog.Activate

    On Error Resume Next

    Range("A" & LRow).Value = CurrentData_FilePath
    Range("B" & LRow).Value = CurrentDateTime
    Range("C" & LRow).Value = ErrorMsg
        Etc....

    wkbErrorLog.Save
    wkbErrorLog.Saved = True

End Sub
```

The error log in this case will look something like the following:

`Error in Sub RT_SETUP_WKBTEMP: Not a .csv or .txt file`
`Error in Sub RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_MAIN`